# IndexedDB: Can you use an array element as a key or an index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, html, indexeddb

Consider the following object store, with the `domain` key set as the `keyPath`

```
var tags  = [ 
    //codes: 0 - markdown wrap tag
    //       1 - HTML wrap tag 
    //       2 - single tag
    { domain: "youtube", 

      bold:["*",0],
      strikethrough:["-",0],
      italic:["_",0] 
    },  


    { domain: "stackoverflow", 

      bold:["<strong>",1], 
      italic:["<em>",1],
      strikethrough:["<del>",1],
      superscript:["<sup>",1],
      subscript:["<sub>",1],
      heading1:["<h1>",1],
      heading2:["<h2>",1],
      heading3:["<h3>",1],
      blockquote:["<blockquote>",1],
      code:["<code>",1],
      newline:["<br>",2],
      horizontal:["<hr>",2]
    }   
];
```

The above code works fine and lets me do look-ups easily and efficiently. However, there are many cases where two objects in the store are completely identical except for their `domain` attribute.

For example, I want to add objects for all of the Stack Exchange sites to the store, and all of those objects would be equal to the one for StackOverflow.

So, rather than create many separate objects, I want to do something like this:

```
var tags  = [ 
    //codes: 0 - markdown wrap tag
    //       1 - HTML wrap tag 
    //       2 - single tag
    { domain: ["youtube"], 

      bold:["*",0],
      strikethrough:["-",0],
      italic:["_",0] 
    },  


    { domain: ["stackoverflow","stackexchange",...], 

      bold:["<strong>",1], 
      italic:["<em>",1],
      strikethrough:["<del>",1],
      superscript:["<sup>",1],
      subscript:["<sub>",1],
      heading1:["<h1>",1],
      heading2:["<h2>",1],
      heading3:["<h3>",1],
      blockquote:["<blockquote>",1],
      code:["<code>",1],
      newline:["<br>",2],
      horizontal:["<hr>",2]
    }   
];
```

Would it be possible to use a `KeyGen` rather than a `keyPath` and set up some kind of index that took a value and searched for it in the arrays pointed to by the `domain` key?

Or would I have to use a cursor each time I want to do a look up?

Some potentially helpful references are:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB
- http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#key-path-construct
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: Have your consider using multiEntry key http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-multientry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use an index with the `multiEntry`  key property set to `true`

see [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-multientry) (thanks @kyaw Tun)

> Each index also has a multiEntry flag. This flag affects how the index behaves when the result of evaluating the index's key path yields an Array. If the multiEntry flag is false, then a single record whose key is an Array is added to the index. If the multiEntry flag is true, then the one record is added to the index for each item in the Array. The key for each record is the value of respective item in the Array.

Armed with this `index`, a specific `keyPath` is no longer necessary, so you can just use a `keyGen` for simplicity.

---

So, to create the database:

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) 
{
   var db = event.target.result;
   var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("domains", {autoIncrement: true });
   objectStore.createIndex("domain", "domain", { unique: true, multiEntry: true });
   for(var i in tags)
   {
       objectStore.add(tags[i]);
       console.log("added " + tags[i]["domain"] + " to the DB");
   }
};
```

and an example of using a domain to query for an object:

```
    var objectStore = db.transaction("domains").objectStore("domains");
    var query = objectStore.index("domain").get(queryURL);
    query.onsuccess = function(event){...};
```

Comment: What's a value of 'queryURL' ?