# Convert an array into an object to create a report javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array that represents a table like this:

```
table =  [['john', 'male', 24, '12/12/12'], ['jane', 'female', 24, 12/12/12]]
```

I want to let the user choose which column they want, so later they can make a pdf report with the columns they chose, I think making an object like this is the best way to get that data, I might be wrong of course haha.

Let's say the user wants the following data on the report header: name, age, date, I want an object like this:

```
userHeader = { name: 'John', age: 24, date: '12/12/12'}
```

So I can make the next report:

```
         Report #1234
 |-------------------------------|
 |Name: John   Date: 24/12/12    |  <-Header
 |Age: 24                        |
 |-------------------------------|
 |some data                      |  <--Body
 | ....                          |
 |-------------------------------|
```

I have an array with the columns the user wants that stores it index, for example if the user wants the columns 1 and 2, the array is this:

```
var userColumns = [1,2]
```

How can I approach this problem? How would you do it?

EDIT: I put the wrong table,. this are the tables:

```
table1 =  [['john', 'male', 24, '12/12/12', 1], ['john', 'male', 24, 01/05/12, 1]]

table2 =  [['john', 'male', 24, '12/07/12', 2], ['john', 'male', 24, 05/05/12, 2]]
```

To get some context, I have a CSV file with multiple columns and rows, each row has a different codeItem, this codeItem can be repeated in multiple rows or not, what i do is create multiple tables that have the same code report, for example if the CSV data has 10 rows, 5 with an codeItem:1 and the other 5 with codeItem: 2, I create 2 tables, one with all the rows that have the codeItem 1 and another with a codeItem 2, then I would make a report for each codeItem, in this case 2 reports, so each table has some rows that have the same data on some columns.
The user columns is what columns the user chose to appear on the report, I have an array with the header columns:

```
var headers = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'date', 'codeReport']
```

What I do is match the index on the header array to the userColumns, lets say the user wants the name and age headers, the user header is:

userHeader = [0, 2]

I know it sounds confusing and it really is.

Comment: What are the columns? Why do you ignore the second array?

Comment: Could you show us what input you've got (`table`) and what code you want to write (such as `extract(table[0])`) and what that code do or return (such as `extract(table[0]) == { name: 'John', age: 24, date: '12/12/12' }`). If that's all correct, that's fine, but that would be easier to understand. Either way, I don't really understand what the `userColumns` thing is about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use objects for storing data from an given array, you need I routine to convert them. Therefor I allways create an empty object `o = {}`, and with `o["prop"] = value` can this object be filled. The same as `o.prop = value`.

```
let headers = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'date', 'codeReport'];
function createObjectFromArray(array, indexes)
{
    let result = {};
    for(let index of indexes)
    {
        result[headers[index]] = array[index];
    }
    return result;
}
let recordObject = createObjectFromArray(['john', 'male', 24, '12/12/12', 1], [1, 2]);
//Object {sex: "male", age: 24}
```

With the help of the ECMAScript 6 class *Map*, it is possible to link an object to any data. Or you can use [IndexedDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032079/indexeddb-can-you-use-an-array-element-as-a-key-or-an-index).

```
let reportDataBase = new Map();
reportDataBase.set(recordObject, "somedata");
reportDataBase.get(recordObject); // "somedata"
```

If you want to iterate through all tables (table 1 has code item 1, table 2 has code item 2, ...), you need an object, which is iterable. I recommend an array.

```
let tables = [table1, table2];
let selectedColumns = [1, 2];
for(var report = 0; report != tables.length; report++)
{
    console.log("report : " + (report + 1));
    tables[report].forEach(function(item)
    {
        console.log(createObjectFromArray(item, selectedColumns));
    });
}
```

I think a better way to storage in-memory data and generate different reports, is to use a data structure like this:

```
var reports = [
    [['john', 24, "somedata1"], ['lara', 22, "somedata2"]],
    [['mark', 21, "somedata3"], ['eve', 25, "somedata4"]]
];
```

But its a bad idea, to storage all personal data in a open browser. To much ressources for showing one record and the question is: Wants the person that his data is public?

One solution is: frontend <-> node.js

Answer (score 0):

You just need an association of table headers with array of user data like

```
ReportHeaderAssociation = {
"0":Name",
"1":Age",
....

}
```

So when you got columns that users want( here [1,2] ) you can get title from association object and value by accessing array element.

Like , `userdata[1]`  will give you second element from data which is gender. Likewise all elements.

***In short***: a single object with relativity will do the job no need to run long loops to convert array to object.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mapping for the column names, for example with the same indexes as the data and a filter for which columns you want.

After that map and reduce are your friends ;)

```js
var table = [
  ['John', 'male', 24, '12/12/12'],
  ['Jane', 'female', 22, '11/11/11']
];

var columnMapping = ['name', 'gender', 'age', 'date'];

var getData = function(data, columnNames, columnFilter) {
  return data.map(function(item) {
    return item.reduce(function(obj, item, idx) {
      if (columnFilter.indexOf(idx) > -1) {
        obj[columnNames[idx]] = item;
      }
      return obj;
    }, {});
  });
}

// age and gender
console.log(getData(table, columnMapping, [1, 2]));

// name and date
console.log(getData(table, columnMapping, [0, 3]));

// name, age and date
console.log(getData(table, columnMapping, [0, 2, 3]));

// name, age and date only if name is John
console.log(getData(table, columnMapping, [0, 2, 3]).filter(function(item) {
  return item.name === 'John';
}));
```